# Issue with jQuery dataTable & columnFilter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm having issue with reinitializing jquery datatable when any search criteria changes with the click of show result button.

It works fine with first load & doing sorting / filtering as expected but if i change criteria & rebuild the table, it is giving me javascript error as "**'oFeatures' is null or not an object**" when (with second load) i try to apply filter by select/deselect any checkbox.

Other info:

jquery.dataTables.js  1.9.4

jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js  1.5.1.

Below code which is used to generate datatable with filter options after getting json result from server & html getting appended to #resultTable

```
var resultTable = $("#resultTable").dataTable({
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "oSearch": { "bSmart": false },
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "aoColumns": [
                   { sWidth: "10px" }
                 , { sWidth: "200px" }
                 , { sWidth: "210px" }
                 , { sWidth: "50px" }
                 , { sWidth: "80px" }
                 , { sWidth: "80px" }
                 , { sWidth: "50px" }
                 , { sWidth: "80px" }
                 , { sWidth: "80px" }
                 , { sWidth: "80px" }
                 , { sWidth: "80px" }
                 , { sWidth: "50px" }
                 ]
}).columnFilter({
    "sPlaceHolder": "head:after",
    "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                { type: "checkbox" },
                { type: "checkbox" },
                { type: "checkbox" },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { type: "checkbox" },
                null,
                null,
                null
               ]
});
```

So far:

I tried applying various options before re-loading datatable like below..

```
 $("#resultTable").dataTable().fnUpdate();

 $("#resultTable").dataTable().fnFilterClear();
```

But no luck yet..!! :(   unable to trace what is wrong in the code!, is it a bug with checkbox filter in plugin? because it works well with select(dropdown) ..!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: furthermore, ``#resultTable`` & html is been created on the fly based on json response from server.

Comment: can someone please help me how to do that work fr select box means dropdown